# Operations on values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two non-unique lists, I would like to zip them into a dictionary in which values for all non-unique keys are a sum. I wonder how it can be done?

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 1]

dct = defaultdict(int)  # create the defaultdict - with 0 as default

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    dct[k] += v

print(dict(dct))  #  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

---

In case you want to use a normal dictionary you could use `dict.get` with zero as default:

```
dct = {}
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    dct[k] = dct.get(k, 0) + v

print(dct)  #  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
outputDict = {}
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 1]
for index, value in enumerate(keys):
   if value in outputDict:
      outputDict[value] += values[index]
   else:
      outputDict[value] = values[index]

print(outputDict)

#The output is {'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 2}
```

Note : A dictionary is unsorted so it doesn't have to be `a,b,c` in order.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through each key to see if it's already in the dictionary, and if so add the two values together:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 1]
new_dict = {}

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
  if k in new_dict:
    new_dict.update({k: new_dict[k] + v})
  else:
    new_dict.update({k: v})

print (new_dict)
```

Seeing as it's a dictionary, the output will be in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular dict:

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d.setdefault(k, 0)
    d[k] += v
```

or default dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d[k] += v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using a regular dictionary with no defaultdict:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 1]

new_dict = {}

for i in zip(keys, values):
   if i[0] in new_dict:
        new_dict[i[0]] += i[1]
   else:
       new_dict[i[0]] = i[1]
```